# How to inject dependencies via a construction delegate

Tags: c#, reflection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I'm using a third-party library that has a setup structure like this:

```
IEngine engine = /* singleton provided elsewhere */

var server = new FooServer();
server.AddService("Data1", () => new Data1(engine));
server.AddService("Data2", () => new Data2(engine));
server.Start();
...
server.Dispose();
```

(The lambda is essentially a factory method; it will internally invoke that whenever it wants a new instance for its own purposes.)

Except that a further complication is that instead of adding the services directly, I'm using reflection to find and register them, so that they just need to be defined to work instead of needing to be explicitly listed out.  Originally I wanted to do this completely self-contained, but constructing generic lambda methods based on reflected types just seemed too complicated, so for the moment I've settled with a `Register` method provided by each type:

```
class Data1 : DataProvider
{
    public static void Register(FooServer server, IEngine engine)
    {
        server.AddService("Data1", () => new Data1(engine));
    }
    ... (constructor, Dispose, other stuff)
}

var server = new FooServer();
foreach (var type in Utils.GetConcreteTypesWithBase<DataProvider>())
{
    var method = type.GetMethod("Register", new[] { typeof(FooServer), typeof(IEngine) });
    if (method != null)
    {
        method.Invoke(null, new object[] { server, engine });
    }
    // a more ideal approach would be to construct the needed lambda and call
    // AddService directly instead of using Register, but my brain fails me.
}
server.Start();
...
server.Dispose();
```

Needless to say, this is a bit ugly and I'm sure there's a better way to do it.  One other thing is that I'm already using Castle Windsor to create the `IEngine` and a few other things that use it, and I was wondering how to better integrate with that.  (Currently I'm just `Resolve`ing the engine at the point where this code needs it -- it's a singleton so lifetimes aren't thorny.)

What I'd really love is a way to use method parameter or constructor injection so that each `DataProvider` could have a different set of parameters based on their actual dependencies (instead of the union of all dependencies), just like you'd do when everything was under Windsor's control.  But again, I'm not sure where to even start.  I haven't really used Windsor much beyond the basics.

Note that `FooServer`, `DataProvider` and the `AddService<T>(string name, Func<T> factory) where T: DataProvider` method are in external code and I can't change them.  The rest (including the engine) is my code.  And again note that I do not create the `Data1` instances in my code at all, just a factory lambda that tells the external server how to create them when it wants one.

---

Following [qujck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27266508/43534) with a few necessary edits resulted in the following code, for posterity:

```
var container = ...;
var server = new FooServer();
foreach (var type in Utils.GetConcreteTypesWithBase<DataProvider>())
{
    var t = type;  // necessary due to the lambda capturing
    container.Register(Component.For(t).LifestyleTransient());
    server.AddService(t.Name, () => {
        var service = (DataProvider) container.Resolve(t);
        service.Closed += (s, e) => container.Release(service);
        return service;
    });
}
server.Start();
...
server.Dispose();
```

This behaves as desired, though I'm still interested in methods to improve it further.  (I was curious if there was some way to use Castle's own `Classes.FromAssembly...` etc syntax to tidy up the discovery and registration of the services, but haven't had much luck working that out.)

Comment: Should the call to `server.Register` inside `DataProvider.Register` actually be `server.AddService`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, brainfart :)  Corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define lambda's that resolve from the container. This offers the benefits of managing all of your services and their related lifetimes in one place (the container).

You would need some way of establishing the name of each registration - in the example I have registered each service as the name of the type:

```
[Fact]
public void Configure1()
{
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    var server = new MockFooServer();

    container.Register(Component.For<IEngine>().ImplementedBy<Engine>());
    foreach (Type type in Utils.GetConcreteTypesWithBase<DataProvider>())
    {
        container.Register(Component.For(type));
        server.AddService(type.Name, () => container.Resolve(type) as DataProvider);
    }

    var service1 = server.services[typeof(Service1).Name]();

    Assert.IsType<Service1>(service1);
}
```

With a Mock `FooServer` for the test:

```
public class MockFooServer
{
    public Dictionary<string, Func<DataProvider>> services = 
        new Dictionary<string, Func<DataProvider>>();

    public void AddService<T>(string key, Func<T> factory) where T : DataProvider
    {
        this.services.Add(key, factory as Func<DataProvider>);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice theory, and that's basically what I was trying to do.  The problem is that (as stated in the question), AddService is defined as `public void AddService<T>(string key, Func<T> factory) where T : DataProvider`.  This makes it quite a pain in the butt to construct a lambda and call it based on a reflected type.  Still, this has given me some ideas so if there are no other answers I'll see if I can muddle through that last bit on my own.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test it yet, but I would be very surprised if that compiled as is.

Comment: @Miral the code here runs just fine and the (xUnit) test passes; but that's not to say the real `FooServer` would work. Let me know how you get on ...

Comment: Oh, I see it now.  I was stuck thinking that `T` had to be the derived type, but you're using the base type instead.  I've been temporarily distracted by other issues and haven't had a chance to test this yet, but I'll get to it soon and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately it does appear that the type matters.  With my original code, changing nothing other than making the lambda use `as DataProvider` at the end causes the server to stop working.  Also note that your example wouldn't work for more than one service -- you need to declare a new local variable for `type` inside the loop and use that in the lambda instead, due to the way that foreaches and lambdas interact.

Comment: Sorry, turns out that was a different issue -- it does actually work with the base type.  But there's still something going wrong when used with Castle; with the lambda at `() => new Data1(engine) as DataProvider` everything runs perfectly, but with it at `() => container.Resolve(t) as DataProvider` it fails.  I've confirmed that `t` is the correct type *and* that `container.Resolve` does actually return an instance of the correct type with the correct engine populated, so I really don't know what's going wrong.

Comment: Aha!  It also needs `LifestyleTransient()` when registering the component type.  Now it works properly, although I'll need to add some additional logic to let it be `Release`d as well.